# tokenize sentence to remove stop words: stop words are not being removed

Tags: python, for-loop, stop-words

My code below should take a sentence from database, tokenize it by word and then remove stopwords accordingly. For some reason when I call the removestopwords function in my for loop it does not work. Any suggestions? When I call the removestopwords function with any inserted sentence it works just fine.

```
import nltk
import random
import csv
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def tokenize(sentence):
    """ This function does the task of converting a sentence into a set of words"""
    t_words = sentence.split()
    return(t_words)

def removestopwords(tokens):
    """This function removes the stop words from the tokens"""
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english")) #get the stop words
    filtered_tokens = list()
    for words in tokens:
        if words not in stop_words:
            filtered_tokens.append(words.lower())
    return filtered_tokens


SENTIMENT_CSV = r"C:\Users\axela\Documents\Decision Support Systems (tilburg)\finance_headlines.csv"
with open(SENTIMENT_CSV, 'rt', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') as sobj:
    sdata = csv.reader(sobj)
    all_tokenwords = list()
    tokenword_label = list()
    for row in sdata: 
        tokens = tokenize(row[1])
        filtered_tokens = removestopwords(tokens)
        all_tokenwords.extend(filtered_tokens)
        tokenword_label.append([filtered_tokens,row[0]])

print(all_tokenwords)
```

I assume something is wrong within my forloop but cannot figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I received an error when trying to run

`from nltk.corpus import stopwords`

The documentation from NLTK says to use the following for stop words

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

nltk.org/data.html

Once I used nltk.download() for the stopwords I slightly modified your function to incorporate list comprehension.

```
def removestopwords(tokens):
    """This function removes the stop words from the tokens"""
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english")) #get the stop words
    return [words.lower() for words in tokens.split(' ') if words not in stop_words]
```

Comment: when adding that line I get and AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: remove the .split(' ') from my code, you may already have it in list form

Comment: removing .split(' ') made the code run but it gave me the same output as my code before. It doesn't remove the stopwords from the list